# What does UMPConsentStatusObtained mean for Consenting with the User Messaging Platform SDK

Tags: ios, admob

I'm looking at https://developers.google.com/admob/ump/ios/quick-start#present_the_form_if_required How can I tell if the user did or didn't agree to personalized ads?

There are only 4 enum:

```
    UMPConsentStatusUnknown: Unknown consent status.
    UMPConsentStatusRequired: User consent required but not yet obtained.
    UMPConsentStatusNotRequired: User consent not required. For example, the user is not in the EEA or UK.
    UMPConsentStatusObtained: User consent obtained. Personalization not defined.
```

Will Google handle user responses automatically in the next Admob request or do I have to somehow figure it out myself?